# unable to navigate page in angularjs

Tags: angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I tried to navigate from aangularjs page to another page but it doesnt work.

My nodejs file is

```
app.get('/signup', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../public/templates', 'test.html'));
    });

module.exports = app;
```

My Angularjs page 1

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app="signApp">
<head>

</head>
<body ng-controller="signCtrl" ui-view="content">    

    <a ui-sref="home">Home</a>
</body>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
<script src="/controller/test.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>

</html>
```

My controller

```
var app = angular.module('signApp', ['ui.router']);

  app.config(function($stateProvider) {
      //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
      $stateProvider
         .state('home', {
             url: 'home',
             views: {
               'content@': {
                 templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
                 controller: 'signCtrl'
               }
             }
           });

   });

  app.controller('signCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
      $state.go('home');
  });
```

My another page is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="signApp">
<head>

</head>
<body ng-controller="signCtrl">    

    <form  ng-submit="regForm()">
      <br> user name:
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.name">
      <br>
      <br> password:
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.password">
      <br>    
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>  
<script src="/controller/test.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.2.15/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

using this code navigation dosen't happen. in url i got a # sign.While using location provider for removing # the link home is going to black. please help me

Answer (score 0):

First, in your controller you forgot to add '/' to the url:

```
var app = angular.module('signApp', ['ui.router']);

  app.config(function($stateProvider) {
      //$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
      $stateProvider
         .state('home', {
             url: '/home',
             views: {
               'content@': {
                 templateUrl: 'templates/register.html',
                 controller: 'signCtrl'
               }
             }
           });
   });

  app.controller('signCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
      $state.go('home');
  });
```

The second thing I noticed that is not right is that your second template contains

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="signApp">
<head>

</head>
<body ng-controller="signCtrl">
```

you don't need all this, you need only the things that you will add to your page once you go to your view.

The third thing is that you should define two separate states 'home' and 'home.register'

```
    .state('home.register', {
        parent: 'home',
        url: '/signup',
        views: {
            '@home': {
                template: 'your template path '

            }
        }
    })
    .state('home', {
        url: '/home',
        views: {

                template: 'your home template'


        }
    });
```